# How to store the data's selected in a selectManyCheckbox into different objects?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In my view I am using `StudentModelBean` to store the data entered in the form. Consider this part of my form:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="English" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hindi" itemValue="Hindi" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Telugu" itemValue="Telugu" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

My requirement is that I need to store each selected item value into the `languageName` property of each `Languages` object. At the end I need to get them in the `List` object. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to provide the whole `Language` objects as both the available items and the selected items. You also need to create a `Converter` which converts between the `Language` object and `String`, this is mandatory because HTML output and HTTP request parameters are one and all `String`.

Assuming that your `Language` object has two properties `code` and `name` and that you've an application scoped bean which look like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Data {

    private List<Language> languages;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        languages= new ArrayList<Language>();
        languages.add(new Language("en", "English"));
        languages.add(new Language("hi", "Hindi"));
        languages.add(new Language("te", "Telugu"));
        // ...
    }

    public List<Language> getLanguages() {
        return languages;
    }

}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedLanguages}" converter="languageConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.languages}" var="language"
        itemValue="#{language}" itemLabel="#{language.name}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

with this bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Language> selectedLanguages;

    // ...
}
```

and this converter

```
@FacesConverter("languageConverter")
public class LanguageConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        return ((Language) object).getCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        List<Language> languages = (List<Language>) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context.getELContext(), "#{data.languages}", List.class);

        for (Language language : languages) {
            if (language.getCode().equals(submittedValue)) {
                return language;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: evaluateExpressionGet is not working with List.class in JSF1.2

Comment: @Beginner: Even more, the whole `evaluateExpressionGet()` method is not available in JSF 1.2. It was added in JSF 2.0. When looking for answers, be careful that you look for JSF 1.x targeted questions, not JSF 2.x targeted ones, otherwise you'll run into endless confusion. JSF 1.x and 2.x are a world of difference.